# Why is my array still filled with 7 elements instead of 6?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file being read from and filled into 3 arrays that are supposed to be of size 7 each. I'm testing to see if my program will recognize that there will only be 6 elements if I delete a number from the text file but when I print out the array lengths for each array they still come out at length 7 and I'm not sure why.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException {



    String file = "input.txt";
    String text = "";
    double [] breakfast = new double [7];
    double [] lunch = new double [7];
    double [] dinner = new double [7];
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(file));
        for (int i = 0;i<7;i++)
        {
            breakfast[i] = s.nextInt();
            lunch[i] = s.nextInt();
            dinner[i] = s.nextInt();


        }
    }
    catch(NoSuchElementException n) {           
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
    }

    if (breakfast.length != 7 || lunch.length != 7 || dinner.length != 7) {
            System.out.println("Your file will not work with this program. Please select another.");
                    System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.println(breakfast.length);
    System.out.println(lunch.length);
    System.out.println(dinner.length);
```

No numbers missing from text file:

```
    800 1000 800
    450 845 1200
    1800 250 400
    0 1500 1800
    600 500 1000
    700 1400 1700
    675 400 900
```

One number missing from text file:

```
    800 1000 800
    450 845 1200
    1800 250 400
    0 1500 1800
    600 500 1000
    700 1400 1700
        400 900
```

Comment: `new double [7]`.

Comment: Because you always initialize them to be of length 7.  Where do you initialize them to any other length?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The array size in Java is fixed after declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021037/the-array-size-in-java-is-fixed-after-declaration)

Comment: You probably want to use a dynamic container such as an [arraylist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 2):

Whether you modify the elements of your collection, your collection will still be the size you initialized it to.

If you initialize a new array with size 7, it will hold the default value of your double: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. This size is final, and you can only change the value of each element, not its existence.
You cannot remove an element unless you re-declare the entire array with a new size, and copy over your elements.

Answer (score 2):

Because you've said you want seven spots (`new double [7]`) and you've filled it by starting with `0` and continuing while `i < 7`. So that's `0 1 2 3 4 5 6` — seven loops.

Also note that your checks later, `if (breakfast.length != 7)` and such, will never be true, because the `length` of an array is fixed as of when you create it (and you've created your arrays with a length of 7). Unused entries have the default value for the type (`0` in the case of `int`).

You might want a `List` instead (such as `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`). Then you could use `theList.size()` to see how many entries it actually has.

Comment: Oh ok, well for this specifically I have to use arrays and fill them with numbers from a text file. I edited my post so you can see what I mean. In this case is it possible to check from the reading of the text file if there is a number missing?

Answer (score 0):

once you declare an array its size remains the same like `String[] s= new String[7];` it will be having size 8 because array indexing starts from 0 not 1 and the size of an array change if you redeclare it again